# cocos2d-js: cc.delayTime() and cc.repeatForever() don't work together in cc.sequence()

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I try to animate three circles with cc.scaleTo() and it works fine up to the moment when i combine cc.delayTime() and cc.repeatForever(). In the hello worlds app I added:

```
 /////////////////////////////
    // 3. add your codes below...

    var contacts = [];

    for( var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++ ) {
        contacts[i] = cc.DrawNode.create();
        contacts[i].retain();
        contacts[i].clear();
        contacts[i].setScale(1);
        contacts[i].drawCircle(cc.p(0,0), 30, 0, 100, false, 2, cc.color(255,0,0,255));
        contacts[i].setPosition(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        this.addChild(contacts[i]);

        contacts[i].runAction(
            cc.sequence(
                cc.delayTime(i),
                cc.repeatForever(
                    cc.sequence(
                        cc.scaleTo(3, 3),
                        cc.scaleTo(0.01, 0)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return true;
```

This is not working and shows the console message:

```
[Action update]. override me
```

When I remove either: cc.delayTime() or cc.repeatForever() it works fine.

```
contacts[i].runAction(
       cc.sequence(
           cc.repeatForever(
                cc.sequence(
                    cc.scaleTo(3, 3),
                    cc.scaleTo(0.01, 0)
                )
            )
        )
);
```

or

```
contacts[i].runAction(
        cc.sequence(
            cc.delayTime(i),
            cc.sequence(
                cc.scaleTo(3, 3),
                cc.scaleTo(0.01, 0)
            )
        )
);
```

And no message appears.

What could that be?

Comment: Truly bizarre.. Have you crated a bud report in the official issue tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put cc.RepeatForever into cc.Sequence, it will not repeat

only finite time actions can be put into sequence

Comment: You are right, it works only if there is no other action in the list. But you have an explanation why only finite time actions are allowed?

Comment: @Michael it's obvilously, if an action in sequence is infinite, the following actions will never be run. if you check the c++ code, action* in CCSequence will be dynamic casted to CCFiniteTimeAction*

Comment: yangguang1029, the following actions never run, ok... but the previous actions also never run.  Take this example above, it does delay time, then a repeating sequence... however the repeat sequence never runs either.

Comment: redux, did you notice my comment? action in sequence will be dynamic casted to FiniteTimeAction*,if can't, it surely not run